# How to write from a particular column in shell?

Tags: shell, sh

I need to write values to a particular column in a text file, say 10th column.

```
touch test.txt
echo "232" >> test.txt           # I want 232 to start from 10th column of text file
```

How to go about ?

Comment: What is a "*column*"?

Comment: If you are talking specifically about echo command, then you have -e option available. With -e option, you can use various backslash ways to format output.

Comment: Say tenth field from a start of a line, I don't want to use tab

Comment: So you want to write this value on 10th column but what about 9 columns before this value? Should they be left blank?

Answer (score 1):

`printf` is another alternative to provide an offset. It has the advantage of being able to take the amount of offset (`field width`) as an argument to the `format specifier`. The following will take the `column offset` as the **first argument** and `the data to write at that offset` as the **second argument** (your defaults of `10/232` are used) for example:

```
#!/bin/sh

col="${1:-10}"                          # column offset (default: 10)
stuff="${2:-232}"                       # variable to write at offset

printf "%*s%s\n" "$col" "" "$stuff"     # write $stuff at $col offset

exit 0
```

To create the `offset`, the `printf` command `format specifier` just says use a `minimum field width` of `$col` to write the `empty-string` (`""`) and thereafter write your data (in `$stuff`) followed by a `newline`. With the script saved as `prncol.sh`:

**output:**

```
$ bash prncol.sh
          232

$ bash prncol.sh 5 501
     501

$ bash prncol.sh 15 anything
               anything
```

Of course to write the output to `test.txt`, just `redirect/append` the output of `printf` to `test.txt`

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in $(seq 10)
do
    echo -n ' '
done

echo "232" >> test.txt
```